Draw Number Spirals, Part 2
In relation to my post from yesterday:
Draw number spirals
I like to find which of the numbers in the OUTER LAYER of the spiral are Prime numbers. For the range of n=1...1000
In doing so, I found the pattern that the outer layer numbers in terms of n are always in this range: between
1+(n-2)^2 and n^2 
ex: n=4 [5-->16] n=5 [10-->25] , etc
Now I like to see which n value generates the MOST primes. I came up with this:
[Expression-1]
Select[Range[1000],Total@Boole@Table[PrimeQ[Range[1 + (# - 2)^2, #^2]]] > 300&]

Which gives me 954
and we can see it is the most and list out those Primes - in fact there are 308 Primes:
[Expression-2]
Intersection[Prime[Range[954^2]], Range[1 + (954 - 2)^2, 954^2]]

However, 2 things I need:

Above had a trial and error - I had to tweak that constant from various values. Is there a way to modify Expression-1 so it finds the MAX value wihtout having to specify the criteria >300 ?

Can we generalize the expression to find all Prime counts for ALL layers (1...1000) and SORT them descending order with counts?


ex:
954==> 308 primes

999==> 299 primes

962==> 298 primes

.....

(those are real values!)

Define a function that counts the number of primes in the range (using PrimePi), and ReverseSortBy that function (note I change the lower bound to be 1 less so that 1 + (n-2)^2 is included if it's also prime:
primeCount := PrimePi[#^2] - PrimePi[(# - 2)^2] &

primeData = {#, primeCount[#]} & /@ Range[1000];
sorted = ReverseSortBy[primeData, Last];

So the 10 largest are:
sorted[[1 ;; 10]] // MatrixForm


To get the n that maximizes PrimeCount we can just use MaximalBy:
maximalPrimeN := First@MaximalBy[Range@#, primeCount] &


so the maximum less than 1000 is 954:
maximalPrimeN[1000]
(*954*)


FWIW we can also define maximalPrimeN recursively, but we have to make the $RecursionLimit infinite (I really don't like how I defined this, I feel like there is a cleaner way to do this):
maximalPrimeNRecursive[1] = 1;
maximalPrimeNRecursive[n_] := maximalPrimeNRecursive[n] =
  Block[{$RecursionLimit = Infinity},
   
   Module[{ maxN, maxCount },
    
    maxN = maximalPrimeNRecursive[n - 1];
    maxCount = primeCount@maxN;
    
    If[primeCount[n] > maxCount,
     n,
     maxN
     ]
    ]
   ]


Thanks so much @ydd  this is amazing...I wonder you missed a +1 in the second part, it should be:  primeCount := PrimePi[#^2] - PrimePi[1 + (# - 2)^2] &   which skews the result by a little!  {
{954, 308},
{999, 299},
{986, 297},
{962, 297},
{982, 296},
{953, 296},
{972, 294},
{963, 292},
{996, 291},
{955, 291}
}

Also if I want to get MAX only, can that be done higher up....is it possible to use the SELECT function with MAX applied to it?

I think you need to offset by a 1 to include the lower bound 1 + (# - 2)^2 if it's prime itself (otherwise it gets double counted by PrimePi[#^2]  and PrimePi[1 + (# - 2)^2] &). To confirm, you can compare it to your original function
$$
$$
primeCountSteve :=   Total@Boole@Table[PrimeQ[Range[1 + (# - 2)^2, #^2]]] &
$$
$$
(primeCountSteve /@ Range[1000]) == (primeCount /@ Range[1000])
(*True*)

Strange.... how can it generate a match when they are clearly different, see my sets above.   the 1+ we need, I calculated this many times! you can visually see it too on the spiral

PrimePi[k] counts the number of primes less than or equal to k. So in the case where 1 + (k - 2)^2 is prime, if I just do PrimePi[k^2] - PrimePi[1 + (k - 2)^2], it will be 1 less than the true answer, because we are subtracting the prime endpoint 1 + (k - 2)^2 . To avoid this, I just decrease the endpoint by 1 to (k - 2)^2, which will allow us to keep 1 + (k - 2)^2 in our range if it's prime, and has no effect otherwise (since (k - 2)^2 is always composite).

When I said "I think you need to offset by a 1 " I probably should have said "I think I need to offset by a 1" because this is just a consequence of me using PrimePi
